# Modify a php file and save it with php

Tags: php

I have a file called config.php that contains only variables.

```
<?php

//General
$domain = "http://www.nine9gag.com"; //Write the url of your website. EX: http://www.nine9gag.com

$waitMsg = "Wait..."; //The message between 2 images.
$buttonText = "Next Image"; //Default: Next Image
```

This is a short piece from entire code.

And i want to create a php script that change the variables with fresh data from a form and save this file.

Wich is the best way to do it?
Thanks!

Comment: Generally it's a bad idea to make PHP scripts editable in any way. Any reason you don't want to store the settings in a database?

Comment: u should use mysql instead, but what do u want to do?

Comment: what did you try so far?  if you're using SQL it's probably best to store the variables there.  If you must use a flat file like this you can use fopen http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php and fclose.

Comment: Because this script does not use DB at all and i don't want to create a DB connection for 14,15 variables.

Comment: Write them to a textfile.

Comment: `file_put_contents` is easier then the fopen/fwrite/fclose routine. As for getting the data into the right format, I’d suggest to use an array as data structure instead of single variables, and using `var_export` to get it in form of valid PHP code.

Comment: Try using a settings file [`.ini`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php), [`.json`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), [`unserialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php), or even a plain text file delimited by newlines.

Comment: As others have said, you should consider a non-PHP storage format.  But sometimes PHP is a practical choice.  In that case, store an array to the file using `var_export()`.

Comment: My website it's like 9gag with funny contents (images,videos) and each "gag"'s details are storred in .txt files like: http://www.nine9gag.com/save/lol-8LUq.txt . It's ok or i have to use DB instead?

Comment: Don't let your code modify itself, this is how SkyNet happens!

Comment: @DaveChen Please write that as an answer (and maybe add XML as an option). The key point is "save to a file" - but so far we seem to be accumulating a separate answer for every possible file format.

Comment: Use an array for your variables and `var_export()` if keeping it in a more-or-less readable php format is your primary concern. (It's not completely infeasible to have editable .php source; but the effort outweighs the benefits. And it's certainly not advisable for data files as you intend.)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to store your data in an database. If that is not an option you should try to store this data in xml file.

**Database**

The good thing of a database is that its real secure. Without password and username you cant connect to it. You can even configure it in a way that just your server can connect to it.

**XML**

A nice clean way to store small information. Its an strict language so its can be used multi-platform. You can use your own attributes and names. To only bad thing is that you need to secure it your self with `chmod` or with security rules.

Comment: My website it's like 9gag with funny contents (images,videos) and each "gag"'s details are storred in .txt files like: nine9gag.com/save/lol-8LUq.txt . It's ok or i have to use DB instead?

Comment: If you can. Please use a database.

Comment: I would suggest you block direct access to .xml files when you go for them, by adding something like this to your .htaccess: `<FilesMatch "\.(xml)$">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>`

Comment: For such an website you should use a database. W3schools wrote a great article about using mysql (a database engine) in combination with php. Maybe you can use that to start (http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp)

Answer (score 0):

U can use fread and fwrite to store variables in file.
U can use json_encode.
Save

```
$json = '{"variable1": 12345,"variable2":6789}';
fwrite($handle,$json,filesize());
```

Load

```
$json = json_encode($json);

$variable1 =  $obj->{'variable1'};12345
$variable2 =  $obj->{'variable2'}; 6789
```

just add works code to read and write

Comment: json encode is less efficient than a simple serialize, and fread/fwrite is probably less desirable than `file_get_contents()`, `file_put_contents()`